# Can I refer to a bibliographic entry with custom text rather a number?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, citing

I'm working on a LaTeX document on Overleaf, with a bibliography in a .bib file. Throughout the document, I'm using `\cite{key}` to get a numeric link to the bibliography and do not want to change that behavior.

I want to be able to refer to a bibliographic entry in specific instances in a way that allows me to use a custom text string. For example:

```
This will be bring me to the right bibliography entry \cite{key}
And I want this to also bring me to the right bibliography entry \hyperref[key]{Custom Text}
```

So far I've tried `\autoref` and `\hyperref`, but, simply put, I don't know how to link to bibliographic items like I could with sections, tables, or figures.

As of right now, my code looks like so:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

Text that is cited \cite{SomeKey}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{litreview.bib}
\end{document}
```

litreview.bib has a bunch of entries formatted as such:

```
@article{SomeKey,
  title={Title},
  author={Author},
  journal={Journal},
  year={Year},
  publisher={Publisher}
}
```

The output looks like:

```
Text that is cited [1]
```

I want to, somewhere else in the paper, be able to \href or \hyperref to the same spot that \cite brings me to, but with my own text rather than [1].

Is there a way to link to a specific entry of the bibliography with custom text?

Comment: The question is tagged with both `biblatex` and BibTeX. Solutions for `biblatex` will be very different from solutions for classical BibTeX. It would help a lot if you could tell us more about your bibliography and citation setup. Ideally you would share a small example document that reproduces the status quo w.r.t. citations and the bibliography with as little unrelated code as possible,

Comment: Thanks so much! I honestly don't know the difference, but I've added some more details? Hopefully that should help? I'm not sure which one I'm using, but it's probably Overleaf's default?

Comment: To help fix ideas, please provide an example of "my own text rather than [1]".

Comment: The code shown in the question is not really the small example document I had in mind (I imagined something starting with `\documentclass` and containing `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) that can be compiled directly without further modifications (what is sometimes called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). But the code shows clearly that you are not using `biblatex`, so I will remove that tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that technically speaking, the argument of `\bibliography` is the base name of the `.bib` file (i.e. the file name *without* extension). So `\bibliography{litreview.bib}` is wrong and should be `\bibliography{litreview}`. (Most modern systems will work just fine if you wrongly include the `.bib` extension here, but it is still a good idea to get rid of it.)

Comment: To follow up on @moewe's request: Do please state which document class you employ, as that piece of information may affect which solution method(s) could be available.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your help everyone :) I'm very new to this! So I appreciate all the communication. Means a lot to be so well received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you load `hyperref` (and an otherwise standard setup) you can use that `hyperref` sets link targets to all bibliography entries. These targets can be accessed as `cite.<entrykey>` with `\hyperlink[cite.<entrykey>]{<link text>}`.

In order to get the same link colour as normal citations, we have to resort to internal commands and end up with the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\citelinktext}[2]{%
  \hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{elk}

\citelinktext{elk}{foo}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arbitrary text with link to bib entry.]

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY!!! Thanks you!!!